# Wordpress Custom Menu Walker

Tags: html, wordpress, class

I am just starting with WP theming and I'm stuck with the walker class. I am trying to output the following code:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" title="">Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="">Menu 2</a></li>
<li class="hasDropdown">
    <a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 1</a>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h5>Description 1</h5>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h5>Description 2</h5>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h5>Description 3</h5>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h5>Description 4</h5>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Menu 3 - Level 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="#" title="">Menu 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="">Menu 5</a></li>
```

I have read numerous articles about the walker class but each does a small portion of what I am trying to do. I would like to bring it all together and get a better understanding. I am unsure how to start / end and setup the menu where it has a drop down level. Please can anyone help? Many thanks in advance.

I have tried copying and amending the walker class found in nav-menu-template as follows:

```
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<div>\n";
    $output .= "\n$indent<h5></h5>\n";
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
}


function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    $output .= "\n$indent</div>\n";
}
```

This gives me the:

```
<div><h5><ul>
```

I am struggling to understand how to achieve the wrapping div and the .hasDropdown

Comment: Can you tell us What steps have you tried taking so far?

Comment: @Dutchie I have provided an example of I've had most success with above. I have tried lots of other customisations to the class but ended up with some very strange results, nothing like what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding one more method. (It is implemented in `Walker` class which `Walker_Nav_Menu` extends).

```
function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

     if (! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] )) {
         $element->classes[] = "hasDropdown";
     }

     parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
}
```

And for wrapping with div element, you have to dig deeper in display_element method (located in `wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php`), but I'm sure you will know what to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. I am having some success also by checking the $depth with an if statement in start / end_el.

Comment: How could I modify your code to output the number of children the element has? So the class name would output "hasDropdown 1" / "hasDropdown 2" and so on.

Comment: `count($children_elements[ $element->$id_field ])` returns number of children current element has. So somthing like this  `if (! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] )) {
         $element->classes[] = "hasDropdown-".count($children_elements[ $element->$id_field ]);
     }` should work.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I got that part working just fine. Still struggling with the HTML formatting but getting there, I think.